# Unable to make use of the right values in params to populate expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, parameters, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape different property links from each of the page out of multiple pages from a website. I know I can use [this url](https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/) to parse the property links using `article[role='presentation'] > .list-card-info > a.list-card-link`. I can even use the same link to process some script tag in order to capture the property links from there.

However, what I wish to do here is to make use of [this link](https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-133.56690190625%2C%22east%22%3A-105.04639409375%2C%22south%22%3A28.39712430131877%2C%22north%22%3A45.47239901246072%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A9%2C%22regionType%22%3A2%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A5%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22con%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22apa%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%2C%22land%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22tow%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22manu%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D) to parse the `detailUrl` from json content.

I'm very close to mimic the requests except for the value of `west`, `east`,`south` and `north`. The following script can parse the values from page source but they are not the right ones compare to what I see them in the dev tools. Given that the values are different in dev tools.

[start page](https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/)

[start page having params](https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-133.56690190625%2C%22east%22%3A-105.04639409375%2C%22south%22%3A28.39712430131877%2C%22north%22%3A45.47239901246072%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A9%2C%22regionType%22%3A2%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A5%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22con%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22apa%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%2C%22land%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22tow%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22manu%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D)

I've tried so far:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/"
link = "https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?"

var = {"pagination":{"currentPage":2},"mapBounds":{"west":"","east":"","south":"","north":""},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":9,"regionType":2}],"isMapVisible":"true","mapZoom":5,"filterState":{"con":{"value":"false"},"apa":{"value":"false"},"mf":{"value":"false"},"sort":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"},"land":{"value":"false"},"tow":{"value":"false"},"manu":{"value":"false"}},"isListVisible":"true"}
params = {
    "searchQueryState": var,
    "includeMap": "false",
    "includeList": "true"
}

page = 2
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(url)
    var['mapBounds']['west'] = re.findall(r"west\":(.*?),",r.text)[0]
    var['mapBounds']['east'] = re.findall(r"east\":(.*?),",r.text)[0]
    var['mapBounds']['south'] = re.findall(r"south\":(.*?),",r.text)[0]
    var['mapBounds']['north'] = re.findall(r"north\":(.*?)}",r.text)[0]
    params['searchQueryState'] = json.dumps(var)

    while True:
        if page==5:break
        res = s.get(link,params=params)
        for item in res.json()['searchResults']['listResults']:
            print(item['detailUrl'])

        page+=1
        var['pagination']['currentPage'] = page
        params['searchQueryState'] = json.dumps(var)
```

***How can I make use of the right value of `west`,`east`,`south` and `north` in params?***

PS The script appears to be working but I can't use the params in the right way.

***Those who are dubious as to whether this script works, please check out [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V6eU.jpg) as a proof of concept.***

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the data you are looking for is loaded by JavaScript after the main HTML is fetched, and your `requests` call will only return that initial HTML. The solution is to use something like `Selenium` to drive an web browser and then after the page has been fully loaded you can then retrieve the resolved source. The following source is an example of how to do that using Chrome. There is however one catch. From time to time, zillow puts up a recaptcha challenge before it loads the desired page. It seemed to me that running Chrome in incognito mode reduced the frequency of that occurrence, but I am no way sure of that. I would normally be running the Chrome driver with the `headless` option to keep the browser invisible. Here I have left it visible just in case the recaptcha is presented although you would probably not be able to solve it in the 5 seconds alloted. In the end there may just not be a good solution since I don't know of a foolproof way of getting around the recaptcha.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re

url = "https://www.zillow.com/ca/houses/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
#options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('map-on-left') # implicitly wait for up to 5 seconds for this element to appear
text = driver.page_source
driver.close()
west_list = re.findall(r"west\":(.*?),", text)
print(west_list)
```

Prints:

```
['-124.482044', '0', '-124.482044}}']
```